# Angular moving from one component to another on button click

Tags: html, angular, bootstrap-4

I want to navigate from one angular component to another on button click. I have two components app and login.On clicking a button in app.component.html I want to navigate to login.component.html. This is what I tried. Though the URL is getting changed, I am not able to see the html content of the page.

app.component.html

```
<div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-9"></div>
    <div class="col-xs-3">

    <input type="button" class="btn btn-primary pull-right" (click)="onSubmit()" value="Next">

    </div>
</div>
```

app.routing.module.ts

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { LogInComponent } from './components/log-in/log-in.component';

const routes: Routes = [{ path: 'login', component: LogInComponent }];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

app.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Router } from '@angular/router'; 
@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  constructor(private router: Router, ) {}  
    onSubmit() {  
        this.router.navigate(['/login'])  
    }  
    ngOnInit() {}  
}
```

log-in.component.html

```
<p>it works</p>
```

On button click the URL changes to /login. However I still see the button UI and not it works. Any help will be appreciated!!Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this would work.

Here is your solution:

```
onSubmit() {  
     this.router.navigateByUrl('/login');
}
```

Another way is:

```
<button class="nav-item" [routerLink]="['/login']"> Login </button>
```

Add in your component:

```
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

Comment: Both of the solution is not working. Am i missing something else?@Kishan Patel

Comment: Can you put your code in any editor which supports typescript so I can able to check the error and all. It's easy to understand

Comment: Please change the onSubmit() calling function. Call after onInit()

Comment: I added <router-outlet></router-outlet> to the app.compoent.html. The login page is getting loaded now however it comes below the app component html.

Comment: Cool! Yup It's required

Answer (score 0):

There are a few things I miss about your code. For one, `app.routing.module` needs to be imported and registered in app.module.ts:

```
import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';

  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    ...
 ]
```

On the other hand, I do not see a router-outlet:

```
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

I would suggest you to use the app component (app.componet.html) maybe like this:

```
<app-navbar></app-navbar> // if you use one
<router-outlet></router-outlet> // this is where the routing happens
```

In the `index.html` you reference the app.component just like that:

```
<body>
  <app-root></app-root>
</body>
```

Then both options suggested by Kishan Patel should work.

Comment: @Fab2 Thanks a lot. will give it a shot!